# Finding an element adjacent to a div that has a specific descendant with css selectors

Tags: xpath, css-selectors

I'm trying to convert the following xpath to find the same element, but using css selectors instead:

```
//div/select[@class='specific_class']/../../button[@type='submit']
```

The HTML looks approximately like the following, and I want the button element.

```
<div>
  <select class="specific_class">
    <options>
  </select>
</div>
<button type="submit">
```

Is this possible using CSS Selectors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, CSS selectors cannot ascend an element hierarchy after descending it. In other words, there isn't any syntax that works like XPath's `..` node, nor is there any syntax to check if a parent element has a certain child element.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Thank you for your help!